# How to resolve Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists error when getting buildid with Azure rest API?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using the below code to retrieve the build id of the latest successful build from the azure pipeline . But throws the below error .Please help in fixing the issue

code :

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 
        $organization = "org_name" 
        $project = "project_name" 
        $definitionid = "27"
        $pat = "eq7pqxcycdp6crbrygwh73ua2kzdvsett3p2sjcx5j"
        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
        $baseUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/build/latest/$definitionid?api-version=5.1-preview.1" 
        $latestbuild = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}  -Method GET 

        Write-Host $latestbuild.id
        $id1 = $latestbuild.id
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildid]$id1"
```

Error :

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

Comment: My agent is a linux box

Answer (score 4):

You need to install Powershell Core on your machine that hosts Azure DevOps agent. This adds `pwsh` to the `PATH`, which will fix your build. [Powershell Core Installation guide for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-linux?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: Then restart the agent so it can pick up the "agent capabilities" and reloads the path and such.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `bash` task, but your script is PowerShell. PowerShell scripts and Bash scripts are not the same thing and can't be used interchangeably. Use a `powershell` (or `pwsh` for PowerShell Core) task instead.

Comment: I have modified the code and now I get a different error "##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'pwsh'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable." How to resolve this ?

Comment: @JCDani You need to install PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the PowerShell core module to your target agent, you can do it easily with bash command:

## Install PowerShell

`sudo apt-get install -y powershell`

After PowerShell install bash task, you should create a PowerShell task it can be Azure CLI as well if you want (just use PowerShell core)[image] just above your code you have to add
`#!/usr/bin/env pwsh`

This fixed my similar issue.